# Text with slash into Json variable for python requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I need to pass text containing slashes into a Json variable when trying to retrieve data from an API. I've tried many ways but keep getting the error EOL while scanning string.

```
    textSent = \"This is my text\"

    payload = """{
    \"language\": \"en\",
     \"text\": textSent
     }"""

   response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload)
```

Some of my attempts include:

```
'\"This is my text\"
"\"This is my text\""
r'\"This is my text\"
```

Note this works:

```
payload = """{
\"language\": \"en\",
 \"text\": \"This is my text\"
 }"""
```

Comment: What's the raw string you are trying to pass as text? It's unclear if you want it to be This is my text, "This is my text", or \"This is my text\"

Comment: I want it to be  \"This is my text\". This will be in the same format as \"en\" @NickBailey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not terminate the string you are trying to assign to `textSent`. You are escaping the last `"` which means this will be part of the string but therefore you are now missing the `"` to tell Python that this is the end of the string. So Python keeps searching for that character but as you never terminate the string in this code line it reaches the end of the line before finding `"`, hence the `EOL`.
In order to send this text as JSON just use [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
Please see the following example program based on your code which shows you two ways to incompass `\` and `"` into your string and send them to an API endpoint as a JSON request body.

```py
import json
import sys

import requests

# Possibility 1: here: use " to declare the string => " and \ must be escaped if they should be part of the string
textSentOnePossibility = "This is my text which contains \\ slashes and \" quotation marks"
# Possibility 2: here: use ' to declare the string => " does not need to be escaped but \ must be escaped if it should be part of the string
textSentAnotherPossibility = 'This is my text which contains \\ slashes and " quotation marks'
print(textSentOnePossibility)
print(textSentAnotherPossibility)

# build dictionary following the structure of your required JSON payload
payload_dict = {
    "language": "en",
    "text": textSentAnotherPossibility
}

# serialize to json
payload_json = json.dumps(payload_dict)

# make request (here: use postman echo API to to the actual request being sent)
resp = requests.post("https://postman-echo.com/post", data=payload_json)
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print("Request failed")
    sys.exit(1)
# print raw json that is returned from the API
print(resp.text)
```

Expected output:

```
This is my text which contains \ slashes and " quotation marks
This is my text which contains \ slashes and " quotation marks
{"args":{},"data":{"lang":"de","text":"This is my text which contains \\ slashes and \" quotation marks"},"files":{},"form":{},"headers":{"x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-forwarded-port":"443","host":"postman-echo.com","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-6227986c-6d094aed6d68bbd63c1c497e","content-length":"90","user-agent":"python-requests/2.27.1","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept":"*/*","content-type":"application/json"},"json":{"lang":"de","text":"This is my text which contains \\ slashes and \" quotation marks"},"url":"https://postman-echo.com/post"}
```

### EDIT

After your comment I think what you are really looking for is just `json.dumps()` which converts the python in-memory structure to the corresponding JSON. There is no need to fiddle around with all the `"`, `\` and so on yourself.
Using `json.dumps()` should be sufficient.
The following program compares the working string you provided above to the one I create with `json.dumps()`.

> Please note: I removed the newlines from your working string to get an exact match using `==` but other than that it is the string you provided.

```py
import json

textSent = "This is my text"

# build dictionary following the structure of your required JSON payload
payload_dict = {
    "language": "en",
    "text": textSent
}
# the string you provided except that I removed the new lines
payload = """{\"language\": \"en\", \"text\": \"This is my text\"}"""

# serialize to json string
payload_json = json.dumps(payload_dict)

# the two texts are equal
print(payload_json)
print(payload)
print(payload_json == payload)
```

Expected output:

```
    {"language": "en", "text": "This is my text"}
    {"language": "en", "text": "This is my text"}
    True
```

If you really wanted to generate something like the string you entered above you could just re-apply `json.dumps()` twice.

```py
import json

textSent = "This is my text"

# build dictionary following the structure of your required JSON payload
payload_dict = {
    "language": "en",
    "text": textSent
}

# apply json dumps twice
payload_json = json.dumps(json.dumps(payload_dict))

print(payload_json)
```

I have used this approach once to send JSON documents in JSON documents as a string, but usually this not required or used by APIs.

Expected output:

```
"{\"language\": \"en\", \"text\": \"This is my text\"}"
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to make sense of your response. Can't really change the Json much as it's the sructure used to retrieve data from an API, I have updated my question to show that using the input for the variable in it's raw format works but errors when i use a variable

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but it does not look like your "Expected output" from the examples above output in the format i require  \"This is my text\"

Comment: I've edited my answer. Still not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I hope my edited version gives you a little bit more insight.

Comment: Went with this payload_json = json.dumps(payload_dict) which worked for me.